# Ruby replace double backslash with single backslash

Tags: ruby, replace, backslash

I cannot seem to replace a double backslash with a single backslash in Ruby. I figured I would just escape the backslashes with another backslash.

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > line = "this\\is\\a\\test"
  => "this\\is\\a\\test"
1.9.3-p194 :002 > line.gsub("\\\\", "\\")  # Nothing
  => "this\\is\\a\\test"
```

That didn't work so I decided to try and find a match that at least makes a replacement.

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > line.gsub("\\", "_")  # This works for replacing \\
  => "this_is_a_test"
1.9.3-p194 :004 > line.gsub("\\", "\\")  # Nothing
  => "this\\is\\a\\test"
```

I still cannot find an easy way to do this in Ruby.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is your string, I had this problem when I got a string that had a `\n` and was interpreted as `\\n`, if that is your case, you should use `line.gsub("\\n", "\n")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this line...

`line = "this\\is\\a\\test"`

... you actually create a string looking like this:

`this\is\a\test`

... as each `\\` will be recognized as a single slash. Of course, you won't be able to replace double slashes, as there's none in your string.

`line.gsub("\\", "_")` line is doing just that: replacing all the *single* slashes in your string with `_` symbol.

`line.gsub("\\", "\\")` is just a no-op in disguise.

Comment: How can we change `line = "this\\is\\a\\test"` to `line = "this\is\a\test"`
gsub did not work in this case

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out. The second parameter should be double quoted:

```
[27] pry(main)> a
=> "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIJKQIBAAKCAgE"
[28] pry(main)> a.gsub('\\n', '\n')
=> "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIJKQIBAAKCAgE"
[29] pry(main)> a.gsub('\\n', "\n")
=> "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIJKQIBAAKCAgE"
[30] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think this will do the job: `str.gsub('\\',"\/")`

Answer (score -4):

This should work for replacing double slashes with single slash:

```
str.gsub(/\\\\/,"\\/")
```

Comment: Unfortunately not :(